# How to automatically Close the Swiper on React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to call a function called `markToDoDone` with a React native gesture handlesr swipeable, but after the swiper is called and the function is called, I have to like swipe the Flatlist item back again to close the swipe and get the item to regain its initial positions, But I want this to be automatic when the function immediately finishes calling, such that immediately the loading is set to false, the list item falls back to its normal position and the swipeable closes.

Kindly help

here is the Swipeable code

```
 <Swipeable
          renderLeftActions={LeftSwipeActions}
          onSwipeableOpen={() => markTodoDone(item.id)}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              alignItems: "center",
              paddingVertical: SIZES.base,
              paddingHorizontal: SIZES.medium,
              backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                borderRadius: 10,
                backgroundColor: item.done ? COLORS.primary : COLORS.graylight,
                marginRight: SIZES.base,
              }}
            ></View>

            <Text
              style={{
                fontFamily: FONTS.regular,
                fontSize: SIZES.font,
                textDecorationLine: item.done ? "line-through" : "none",
                flex: 1,
              }}
            >
              {item.title}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Swipeable>
```

And then here is the code to call marktodo

```
 const markTodoDone = async (todoId) => {
setTodoLoading(true);
const todoData = {
  todo_id: todoId,
  fruit_id: fruitId,
};

try {
  const res = await client.post("/mark-todo", todoData);
  console.log(res.data);
  if (res.data.status == 200) {
    Toast.show({
      type: "success",
      text1: "Mark from Frutunda",
      text2: "You have markeed Activity done",
    });
    fetchFarmFruitTodos(fruitId);
  }
} catch (error) {
  Toast.show({
    type: "error",
    text1: "Mark from Frutunda",
    text2: "Oops! Something went wrong",
  });
}
setTodoLoading(false);
```

};